# "Click through" panel on form, not the form itself

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, transparency

So I have been searching for a while now and I am having trouble finding a solution for it.

My situation is that I have a form in which I want a 3 pixel padding on all sides. I then want a panel docked to the form and set the back color of that panel to the transparency key of the form (Lawn Green). This would create the following effect:

[image: Example]

So I have found a lot of solutions that reference making the form "Click Through" but not any controls on a form. So the first question is: Is this possible?

If it is, then I am sure I can modify the code for making the form "Click Through" to work for a panel instead.

Below is the code I have gotten so far:

```
Public Enum GWL
    ExStyle = -20
End Enum

Public Enum LWA
    ColorKey = &H1
    Alpha = &H2
End Enum

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")>
Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")>
Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As GWL, dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")>
Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd As IntPtr, crKey As Integer, alpha As Byte, dwFlags As LWA) As Boolean
End Function

Private Sub Me_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim MyLongOne As Integer = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle)
    SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, MyLongOne Or &H80000 Or &H20)
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255, LWA.Alpha)
End Sub
```

As you can see, the fact that this code uses "Me.Handle", this is still referencing the form itself. What would I need to change to get this to be only the panel on the form?

I have changed it to "Me.Panel1.Handle" but it does not work.

Comment: An alternative you can use is to have `event handler` for `MouseDown` events for both your `Panel` and your `Form`. Then when the `event` occurs in your `Panel` you simply call the `event handler` in your `Form`

Comment: See question again for amendment ^

Comment: You cannot use SetLayeredWindowAttributes() on a child control, it must be a toplevel window.  A Form.  Making it click-through is simple, just set the panel's BackColor property the same as the form's TransparencyKey.  You have to avoid an Aero bug however, some color key values are not transparent to the mouse.  Like LimeGreen.  Use Color.Fuchsia.

Comment: It annoys me how simple that is, I was using "LawnGreen" and it was not working. Switched it to "Thistle" and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!